# generate queries for each key in pyspark data frame

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data frame in `pyspark` like below

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
[
('2021-10-01','A',25),
('2021-10-02','B',24),
('2021-10-03','C',20),
('2021-10-04','D',21),
('2021-10-05','E',20),
('2021-10-06','F',22),
('2021-10-07','G',23),
('2021-10-08','H',24)],("RUN_DATE", "NAME", "VALUE"))
```

Now using this data frame I want to update a table in `MySql`

```
# query to run should be similar to this
update_query = "UPDATE DB.TABLE SET DATE = '2021-10-01', VALUE = 25 WHERE NAME = 'A'"

# mysql_conn is a function which I use to connect to `MySql`  from `pyspark` and run queries
# Invoking the function 
mysql_conn(host, user_name, password, update_query)
```

Now when I invoke the mysql_conn function by passing parameters the query runs successfully and the record gets updated in the `MySql` table.

Now I want to run the update statement for all the records in the data frame.

For each `NAME` it has to pick the `RUN_DATE` and `VALUE` and replace in `update_query` and trigger the mysql_conn.

I think we need to a `for loop` but not sure how to proceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of iterating through the dataframe with a for loop, it would be better to distribute the workload across each partitions using [`foreachPartition`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.foreachPartition.html). Moreover, since you are writing a custom query instead of executing one query for each query, it would be more efficient to execute a batch operation to reduce the round trips, latency and concurrent connections. Eg

```py
def update_db(rows):
    temp_table_query=""
    for row in rows:
        if len(temp_table_query) > 0:
            temp_table_query = temp_table_query + " UNION ALL "
        temp_table_query = temp_table_query + " SELECT '%s' as RUNDATE, '%s' as NAME, %d as VALUE " % (row.RUN_DATE,row.NAME,row.VALUE)
  
    update_query="""
        UPDATE DBTABLE 
        INNER JOIN (
            %s
        ) new_records ON DBTABLE.NAME = new_records.NAME
        SET 
            DBTABLE.DATE = new_records.RUNDATE, 
            DBTABLE.VALUE = new_records.VALUE 
    """ % (temp_table_query)
    mysql_conn(host, user_name, password, update_query)
    

df.foreachPartition(update_db)
```

[View Demo on how the UPDATE query works](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/4BxBE2ajyunVdLc3FGyzue/1)

Let me know if this works for you.